# R Programming: Air Pollution - Pollutant Mean

Tags: r, csv

This is the first time I'm trying to import multiple CSV files in R and to solve that part of the assignment, using some of the csv files to calculate the mean of sulfate and nitrate. I searched for answers here in stackoverflow and other sites but I wasn't able to fix that issue based on what is told in questions here about the topic. I'm also new in R Programming.

If its useful:
R version is 3.2.1
Mac OS X version 10.7.5

I have an assignment in Coursera where I have 332 CSV files that I have to calculate the mean of pollutants.

Link to download the file: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2Fspecdata.zip

**Assignment Part 1:**

Write a function named 'pollutantmean' that calculates the mean of a pollutant (sulfate or nitrate) across a specified list of monitors. The function 'pollutantmean' takes three arguments: 'directory', 'pollutant', and 'id'. Given a vector monitor ID numbers, 'pollutantmean' reads that monitors' particulate matter data from the directory specified in the 'directory' argument and returns the mean of the pollutant across all of the monitors, ignoring any missing values coded as NA.

**Prototype of the function:**

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
## 'directory' is a character vector of length 1 indicating
## the location of the CSV files

## 'pollutant' is a character vector of length 1 indicating
## the name of the pollutant for which we will calculate the
## mean; either "sulfate" or "nitrate".

## 'id' is an integer vector indicating the monitor ID numbers
## to be used

## Return the mean of the pollutant across all monitors list
## in the 'id' vector (ignoring NA values)
```

My outcome should be that:

```
source("pollutantmean.R")
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
## [1] 4.064
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72)
## [1] 1.706
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
## [1] 1.281
```

I already created my working directory and this is were I wasn't able to go further.

```
> setwd("~/Desktop/Coursera /R_Prog")
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/amandamariamcharpinel/Desktop/Coursera /R_Prog"
> dir()
[1] "specdata"     "specdata.zip"
> directory <- "specdata"
> filelist <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
> pollutantmean<-function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332)
```

Whenever I try to do use F1 <-read.csv("name of the file", header=TRUE) the error that appears is **Error in file(file, "rt") : not possible to open a connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : not possible to open the file 'nameoffile.csv': No such file or directory**
When I use the command read.table(filechoose(), header=TRUE) works for all the files except for the first file (001.csv) which says **Error in scan (file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 1 don't have 7 elements** 
When I try sapply(filelist, read.csv) appears the same error. When I use read.csv, sapply or lapply for the "specdata" the error is **Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,: no lines available in input** although I have all the 332.csv files in the "specdata" file.

I hope I posted everything needed for a reproducible exercise. If there is anything more needed, just let me know.

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=r+pollutantmean. Good luck.

Comment: You may want to read the [open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and consider revising or removing your question.

Comment: Well, I tried to solve the bugs I was having in the assignment based on other questions about the assignment here in stackoverflow but I wasn't able to solve the problems based on the answers of other questions about that assignment. That's why I asked that question here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set your directory as:

```
directory<-"/Users/amandamariamcharpinel/Desktop/Coursera /R_Prog/specdata"
```

Since your files are in the specdata folder, r needs to be pointed through the complete file path.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP already has done.

Comment: Thanks :)  This is interesting, because I tried to solve this in another forum, but they told me I should maintain my directory as "/Users/amandamariamcharpinel/Desktop/Coursera /R_Prog". The difference is when I set the directory as the one you told me is that I can open some of the CSV files with read.csv but the 001.csv continues to give me problem. Error in file(file, "rt") : not possible to open a connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : not possible to open the file 'nameoffile.csv': No such file or directory.